# How to set variable on value change (select input)?

Tags: javascript, html, nunjucks

I have a price variable initialized at 12

```html
{% set price = 12 %}
```

I want to change the value of this variable if the user selects another option in my select input field

```html
      <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
      <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
        <option value="{% set price = 24 %}">2</option>
        <option value="{% set price = 36 %}">3</option>
        <option value="{% set price = 48 %}">4</option>
      </select>
```

I tried directly in value to set the new value but it does not work.

Can I watch an event with an onChange property in nunjucks?

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance !

Comment: Use `vue` or `react`. `Nunjucks` doesn't have a two sides binding because it's a just a render engine. Or add `onchange`-listener e.g. `<select name="quantity" id="quantity" onchange="your-function">`

Comment: @AikonMogwai yes that's what I finally did, I use a js function ! Thx for ur reply